# Set cookies on file upload in PHP

Tags: php

I have a php upload handler in upload.php, and there, I have to following

```
<? setcookie("test",100,time()+3600); ?>
```

but, when I check the cookies that are set, I dont see any "test" cookie at all.

Can you please help me set a cookie on file upload? why is this upload script any different from any normal script that is accessed by the browser?

Here is the code I have

```
<?php           
 if (!empty($_FILES)) {            
    if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile))
        {               
                setcookie("targetPath",$targetPath,time() + 3600,'/');
                print $_COOKIE['targetPath']; // prints fine here
                echo 1;
        }
        else
                echo -1;} 
else
{
//print_r($_COOKIE);
print "start cookie >> ";
print $_COOKIE['targetPath']; // does not print when I call upload.php standalone
print " << end cookie";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not solve your problem, but I thought I should point it out:

1. setcookie needs to be called prior to any output, unless you are using output buffering.
2. The first argument to move_uploaded_file should be something like `$_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][0]`
3. Cookies set with setcookie don't show up until the next page load. And yes, this is [documented](http://www.php.net/setcookie) in the PHP manual:

   > Once the cookies have been set, they
   >   can be accessed on the **next page load**
   >   with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS
   >   arrays.

   This means that this code:

   setcookie("targetPath",$targetPath,time() + 3600,'/');
   print $_COOKIE['targetPath']; // prints fine here

   should print the cookie's *old* value.
4. setcookie returns false if it fails.  You might want to check that return value.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the domain?

```
<?php    
setcookie( 'test', 100, time()+3600, '/', '.sitename.com' );
```

Are you fetching it with `$_COOKIE['test']` ?

PS - You should not be using short tags. Replace `<?` with `<?php`.

Comment: The domain notation is just `.example.com` and not `*.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking to see if cookies are set in upload.php, ie. the same script you set them? If so, I wouldn't expect them to be set. The cookie will be sent by the client on the next HTTP request after they have received the cookie from upload.php.

Answer (score 0):

setcookie has **"path"** argument. If it is not specified: "The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in."
So most likely you're trying to set cookie for something like www.youdomain.com/actions/upload.php and in that case cookie will be set for /actions/ path.

Also check that call setcookie is done **before** any output from your script